# NiceArray unknown issue

Tags: errors, nicematrix

I'm trying to compile the simplest MWE with `NiceArray` environment from [`nicematrix`](https://ctan.org/pkg/nicematrix) package

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{NiceArray}{ccc}
1 & 2 & 3
\end{NiceArray}
\]

\end{document}
```

The PDF compiles, but I'm receiving an unexpected error

```
! Package nicematrix Error: There is a problem. Maybe your environment
(nicematrix)                {NiceArray} is empty. Maybe you have used l, c
(nicematrix)                and r instead of L, C and R in the preamble of
(nicematrix)                your environment.
(nicematrix)                If you go on, the result may be incorrect.
```

Full log: [here](https://pastebin.com/raw/Prb2NSCs)

Comment: Please not that what you show here is a compilation error. Just because you got a pdf does not mean that the document successfully compiled.

Comment: The example compiles without issues on TeXLive 2022. You're using TeXLive 2019. I just tested using TeXLive 2019 and I get the same error as you do. You need to follow the manual that belong to the NiceArray version in TL2019. For example by adjusting the example as the error says, aka replace `ccc` by `CCC`

Comment: @daleif interesting. Where are those uppercase column types are described? Can't find a dedicated section in the manual of nicematrix.

Comment: They are listed in the error message. Plus since you're using an old nicematrix you need to look in the corresponding old manual or update your latex installation

Comment: @daleif oh, you're right. Just found that manual and there it's exactly described: https://i.stack.imgur.com/j5QqG.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [daleif](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/3929/daleif) for pointing me into the problem in comments.

Indeed, the manual of my old version of nicematrix's that I'm using, basically describes that

[image]